# Could Paul Atreides have navigated a space fold?

Tags: dune

In the classic [Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel)) Paul Atreides becomes the long sought Bene Gesserit [super being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bene_Gesserit#Breeding_program). He is both the first ever successful male Bene Geserit as well as a mentat, with tremendous prescient ability. It is also know that the Spacing Guild [Navigators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guild_Navigator) navigational abilities require at least limited prescience to safely traverse space.

**As the Kwisatz Haderach could Paul Atreides have navigated a [fold-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holtzman_effect)?**

> To this effect, the Guild produces melange-saturated Navigators who intuitively "see paths through foldspace" in this way.

[Guild Navigator folding space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md_pOrpsw9c)

Comment: My gut instinct says "yes", largely based on the fact that his abilities as a seer far exceeds theirs. There may, however be some kind of practice required.

Comment: Same, based solely as you say on instinct, I can't find definitive proof yet. As I know, it the [Holtzman Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holtzman_effect) did the actual folding, the Navigators job was to use prescience to mitigate the [quantum uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holtzman_effect#Holtzman_drive).

Comment: OK. I've found an answer in "The Battle of Corrin". Norma Cenva (a human) uses a  space trance to navigate a fold through a form of prescience. Given that her abilities are dwarfed by Paul's, it seems logical that he could easily perform the function of a Navigator if he wanted to.

Comment: Write it up if you want to. I barely recognise these books as being part of the Dune universe. As far as I'm concerned they're only one step above fanfic

Comment: Jeez, I feel exactly the same, it's actually a _chore_ to wade through them. Thx again.

Comment: @Richard norma cenva is actually on the short list for most powerful entity in the universe she literally looses her physical body and lives in a spiritual state. shes still alive after close to 10k years. lol

Comment: You are right. I read that as 'dwarfs Paul' not 'dwarfed by'. But I still think he's correct about this possibility. Good catch thx!

Comment: As a sidenote: IIRC, in the books, the navigators do not fold space (technology does this) but really only navigate through foldspace, which is however difficult enough to require special abilities. In Lynch’s movie, their are actually said to fold space. I am not sure about the TV movies.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Absolutely correct, see my [comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110315/could-paul-atreides-have-navigated-a-space-fold#comment262145_110315) above regarding the Holtzman Device. I don't feel that I have enough to make the Norma Cenva statement. If you can find that, put it in an answer and I'll accept it. Thx bud!

Comment: I don't have the exact reference immediately to hand, but I remember in _Dune_, Paul looking for possible alternatives to the futures he's been seeing, and seeing one where he seeks asylum with the Guild, who would not find his abilities strange. There is some implication there that he could have learned to navigate -- to basically deliberately limit his vision the way the Navigators did to seeking the safe path. In the end, of course, that's exactly what he and Leto II reject...

Comment: Holy smokes! Put that in an answer when you find it.

Comment: Pauls prescient awareness - living moment to moment navigating by understanding "the now" sounds quite a bit like walking instead of driving a car.  Guild navigation is like driving the car - and that is a lot easier than walking. Paul had to move his own legs, and suffer the costs of his own thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand what you said, and can you give a reference or logical deduction as to how you arrive at some of your claims such as: `Guild navigation is like driving the car... ` etc. Maybe you could formulate an answer for thix? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no evidence that Paul was a mentat, but rather he had some mentat training from Thufir Hawat.

Reverend Mother Mohaim indicates to Paul during Chapter 1 that the Spacing Guild emphasizes almost Pure Mathematics:

> She nodded. "We have two chief survivors of those ancient schools: the Bene Gesserit and the Spacing Guild. The Guild, so we think, emphasizes almost pure mathematics. Bene Gesserit performs another function."

This is math training different from being a 'mentat'.  However, it would stand to reason that this training is related to the actual navigation of the ships through fold space.

A second part of navigation is the spice-based prescience which allows prediction of the paths ahead.  Paul, being Kwiswatz Haderach, could see the paths ahead, and thus has half of this combination.  However, lacking the pure mathematics training, it is unlikely he could navigate a ship until he actually got some coaching in the matter.

It is possible that this knowledge might be present in 'other memories', but this also seems unlikely since that would require a Guild navigator (or adept, at least) have previously been part of the Bene Gesserit breeding program in lineal antecendence to Paul.  Given the paragraph quoted above, combined with the general sense of xenophobic both organizations exhibit, this also seems unlikely.

While not explicitly addressed (and likely such a task would be beneath the emperor anyhows), it seems unlikely Paul could actually navigate a Guild vessel.

Comment: Holy smokes. This is a novel idea, it was the _special_ math training that allowed the Guild Navigators to actually _plot the course_ through space, and Paul didn't receive it. You are right, I mean why else even study the math. Sure it was the spice that gave the prescience ability, but their math skills allowed for what must have been a mind-numbing computation. Norma Cenva _was_ a mathematician as she was suggested above. _Excellent_ answer. Thx!

Comment: Least anyone think [intuition](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Poincare_Intuition.html) is not a critical math skill. Poincaré was first rate math genius.

Comment: Paul's other memories would contain some of the finest mathematicians who'd ever lived. I'm not sure you can point to that as being a logical gap in his knowledge.

Comment: Specifically, I am saying Paul is not likely to have the Navigator's specific knowledge.  I concur he likely had a lot of 'precursor' knowledge that would allow him to redevelop said skills, but we have no reason to believe he is naturally talented to put all the pieces together instantaneously.  The nature of other memory is a murky, and I am not comfortable asserting the other memories could generate this knowledge for him.

Comment: Can't upvote Poincare comment enough.

Comment: @Richard Other Memory is like a library, a set of information that a person can reference, it's not knowledge/skill in and of itself. Also what would happen if someone let an Other Memory take over, even a fine mathematician, consider what happened to Alia, sounds like very dangerous business.

Comment: Also there is no guarantee even in all the other memory there is a trained Navigator, recall that the Guild was a totally separate school from the BG and the Mentats.

Comment: @AthenaWidget true, but there are likely billions of other people available in Paul's ancestors.